# Localhost:5000/gigs doesn't load

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, sequelize.js, localhost

I was exactly following this traversy media vid : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bOHysWYMZM0
and my localhost:5000/gigs is hanging and never loads. It doesn't even give any error and the terminal works fine as well (database query is returned in terminal successfully)

Here's the code for the gigs page:

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const db = require('../config/database');
const Gig = require("../models/Gig");

router.get('/', (req,res) => 
    Gig.findAll()
        .then(gigs => {
            console.log(gigs);
            res.sendStatus(200);
        })
        .catch(err => console.log(err)));

//res.send("Hello there")
module.exports = router;
```

I think the problem lies in the findAll function as I replaced that with a simple res.send('Hello') message and the page loaded.

EDIT: I have found the problem, actually sequelize.js automatically adds a 's' to the table name that I'm using to fetch the data. So the terminal data was actually not correct, and this code is okay. Thanks to everyone who answered.

Comment: Use `res.sendStatus(200).end()`. Without a [`res.end()`](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.end) or similar the response is never completed.

Comment: Nah, doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

I have found the problem, actually sequelize.js automatically adds a 's' to the table name that I'm using to fetch the data. So the terminal data was actually not correct, and this code is okay. Thanks to everyone who answered.